# How to apply colors in powershell output

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell

Requirement :

I am beginner in powershell. Below ps script is giving the details about services are in started state or in stopped state but my requirement is I need to see this out put as background color in 'Sky Blue', if services are running then highlight in Green ,Stopped services in Red color. How do I achieve it.

Help on this is highly appriciated.

```
$Result = @() 
foreach($server in Get-Content C:\PowerSQL\List.txt) 
{ 
$Services=gwmi win32_service -computername $server | where {$_.Name -like ‘*SQL*’} 
if(!(Test-Connection -Cn $server -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet)) 
{“Problem still exists in connecting to $server”} 
ELSE { 
$services | ForEach { 
If ($_) 
{ $Result += New-Object PSObject -Property @{ 

‘Host Name’ = $_.Systemname 
‘Service Display Name’ = $_.Displayname 
‘Service Name’ = $_.Name 
‘Start Mode’ = $_.Startmode 
‘Service Account Name’ = $_.Startname 
‘State’ = $_.State 
‘Status’= $_.Status 
 } 
} 
} 
} 
} 

$Result | ConvertTo-HTML | Out-File C:\PowerSQL\service.htm
```

Answer (score 1):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39486625/1368849) to similar question to this.

Communary.ConsoleExtensions [[link]](https://communary.net/2016/09/10/communary-consoleextensions/) might help you

```
Invoke-ColorizedFileListing C:\Windows -m *.dmp
```

The above command will colorise file types and highlight dump files.

To save a color output, you would have to save to a format that preserves color, like RTF, or HTML. Txt (plain text file) only stores text.

The code below will save your output as an html file.

```
$time = (Get-Date).AddYears(-2)
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $time} |
Select Directory,Name,LastWriteTime |
ConvertTo-Html -Title "Services" -Body "<H2>The result of Get-ChildItem</H2> " -Property Directory,Name,LastWriteTime |
ForEach-Object {
  if ($_ -like '<tr><td>*') {
    $_ -replace '^(.*?)(<td>.*?</td>)<td>(.*?)</td>(.*)','$1$2<td><font color="green">$3</font></td>$4'
  } else {
    $_
  }
} | Set-Content "$env:TEMP\ColorDirList.html" -Force
```

The line:

```
if ($_ -like '<tr><td>*') {
```

...checks for line in the html output that is a table row.

The line:

```
$_ -replace '^(.*?)(<td>.*?</td>)<td>(.*?)</td>(.*)','$1$2<td><font color="green">$3</font></td>$4'
```

...uses a RegEx to replace the 2nd table cell contents with a font tag with the color green. *This is a very simple RegEx search & replace that will only color the 2nd column*.

And here's another implementation of *console only* coloring, based on [this link](http://www.bgreco.net/powershell/format-color/)

```
$linestocolor = @(
'CSName         Version        OSArchitecture'
'------         -------        --------------'
'BENDER         6.1.7601       64-bit        '
'LEELA          6.1.7601       64-bit        '
'FRY            6.1.7600       64-bit        '
'FARNSWORTH     6.1.7601       32-bit        '
)


# http://www.bgreco.net/powershell/format-color/
function Format-Color {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
      [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,Mandatory=$true)]
      $ToColorize
    , [hashtable]$Colors=@{}
    , [switch]$SimpleMatch
    , [switch]$FullLine
    )
  Process {
    $lines = ($ToColorize | Out-String).Trim() -replace "`r", "" -split "`n"
    foreach($line in $lines) {
      $color = ''
      foreach($pattern in $Colors.Keys){
        if     (!$SimpleMatch -and !$FullLine -and $line -match "([\s\S]*?)($pattern)([\s\S]*)") { $color = $Colors[$pattern] }
        elseif (!$SimpleMatch -and $line -match $pattern) { $color = $Colors[$pattern] }
        elseif ($SimpleMatch -and $line -like $pattern) { $color = $Colors[$pattern] }
      }
      if ($color -eq '') { Write-Host $line }
        elseif ($FullLine -or $SimpleMatch) { Write-Host $line -ForegroundColor $color }
        else {
        Write-Host $Matches[1] -NoNewline
        Write-Host $Matches[2] -NoNewline -ForegroundColor $color
        Write-Host $Matches[3]
      }
    }
  }
}

$linestocolor | Format-Color -Colors @{'6.1.7600' = 'Red'; '32-bit' = 'Green'}

# doesn't work...
# (Get-ChildItem | Format-Table -AutoSize) | Format-Color -Colors @{'sql' = 'Red'; '08/07/2016' = 'Green'}
# does work...
Format-Color -ToColorize (Get-ChildItem | Format-Table -AutoSize) -Colors @{'sql' = 'Red'; '08/07/2016' = 'Green'}

return
```

**EDIT. to answer the OPs request**

```
$Result = @()
foreach($server in Get-Content C:\PowerSQL\List.txt)
{
  $Services=gwmi win32_service -computername $server | where {$_.Name -like ‘*SQL*’}
  if(!(Test-Connection -Cn $server -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))
    {“Problem still exists in connecting to $server”}
  else {
    $services | ForEach {
      If ($_)
        { $Result += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        HostName = $_.Systemname
        ServiceDisplayName = $_.Displayname
        ServiceName = $_.Name
        StartMode = $_.Startmode
        ServiceAccountName = $_.Startname
        State = $_.State
        Status = $_.Status
        }
      }
    }
  }
} 

$Result | ConvertTo-HTML `
  -Title "Services" `
  -Body "<H2>The result of gwmi win32_service</H2> " `
  -Property HostName,ServiceDisplayName,ServiceName,StartMode,ServiceAccountName,State,Status |
ForEach-Object {
  if ($_ -like '<tr><td>*') {
    switch ($_) {
      { $_ -like '*<td>Stopped</td>*' } {$color='red'}
      { $_ -like '*<td>Running</td>*' } {$color='green'}
      Default                           {$color='white'}
    }
  $_.Replace('<tr>', "<tr bgcolor=`"$color`">")
  } else {
  $_
  }
} | Set-Content C:\PowerSQL\service.htm -Force
```

Comment: Many thanks TechSpud for your reply. I am not able to apply your logic to my code so could you please apply your logic on my code and paste here

Comment: Great Tech Spud. Could you please help me  by keeping the column headers such as HostName,ServiceDisplayName,ServiceName,StartMode,ServiceAccountName,State,Status with borders.

Comment: @Franklin What do you mean by borders? HTML borders? If you want to style the table, run `Get-Help ConvertTo-Html -Full`. You can specify the location of a stylesheet to attach to the generated html. Search/Google for css table styling. If you mean keeping spaces in your property attributes, then wrap them and all references to them in single quotes. I feel I've answered your question, so could you mark this as the answer, if so, please? I need to leave you a little work to do yourself :)

Comment: I mean headings. Thank you for you time Spud.I marked it as answer.