# Converting data from text file to html

Tags: powershell

I’m working on one of my final big assignments for this powershell class and I’m struggling trying to figure out the proper use for regular expressions. Basically, I’m stuck trying to get the html file exported correctly and using the student ID properly. Again, any help with this is appreciated. Thank you!

Instructions:
Using PowerShell ISE or VSCode, create a PowerShell script that will do the following:

You are going to create an HTML web page report from a standard processed report. You will use the text file “STUDENTS.TXTPreview the document” located on Canvas.

The script must meet the following requirements:

The output file should be named ITS3410-{your name}.htm
Every line of data that has a student number (9999-9999) must be included in the report
All data must be trimmed
No leading white space
No trailing white space
No empty values
No garbage lines
The student number MUST be detected using regular expression (regex)
You must include comments in your code to explain it
The report headers must be visible on the HTML web page

```
########SCRIPT######################
$inputFile = Get-Content c:\powershell\STUDENTS.txt    #getting input file
$output_file = 'c:\powershell\ITS3410-myname.htm'       #to get the output file


$FileLine = @()
Foreach ($Line in $inputFile) {
$MyObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
#adding the objects
Add-Member -InputObject $MyObject -Type NoteProperty -Name Student# -Value $Line
Add-Member -InputObject $MyObject -Type NoteProperty -Name LAST -Value $Line
Add-Member -InputObject $MyObject -Type NoteProperty -Name FIRST -Value $Line
Add-Member -InputObject $MyObject -Type NoteProperty -Name DN -Value $Line
Add-Member -InputObject $MyObject -Type NoteProperty -Name ERN -Value $Line
Add-Member -InputObject $MyObject -Type NoteProperty -Name HR -Value $Line
Add-Member -InputObject $MyObject -Type NoteProperty -Name STS -Value $Line
Add-Member -InputObject $MyObject -Type NoteProperty -Name DEG -Value $Line
Add-Member -InputObject $MyObject -Type NoteProperty -Name CON -Value $Line
Add-Member -InputObject $MyObject -Type NoteProperty -Name VER -Value $Line
Add-Member -InputObject $MyObject -Type NoteProperty -Name GPA -Value $Line

$FileLine += $MyObject
}
#to convert the script into html
$FileLine | ConvertTo-Html -Property Student#, LAST, FIRST, DN, ERN, HR, STS, DEG, CON, VER, GPA - 
body "<H2>Student Report</H2>" | Out-File $output_file

Invoke-Expression $output_file
$line = "9999-9999  Denty Bryon N  72 8     4       CER CSC      2006A          3.43"
$strings = $line -split " " | Where-Object { $_ }
# Bulk add properties
$props = @{
               StudentID = $strings[0]
               Surname =   $strings[1]
               Firstname = $strings[2]
               DN = $strings[3]
               ERN = $strings[4]
               HR = $strings[5]
               STS = $strings[6]
               DEG = $strings[7]
               CON = $strings[8]
}

# Add more properties by name
$props["VER"] = $strings[9]
$props["GPA"] = $strings[10]
```

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML modules via the MS powershellgallery.com.  `Find-Module -Name '*html*'`

Comment: You have not really provided enough information - there is no source data to work with in the first place. Regex is most likely used for parsing data - for what it's worth - there's most likely some patterns you can replicate with regex and then use these to assign the resulting matches to a variable with,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert text table to HTML table in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43206260/how-to-convert-text-table-to-html-table-in-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

#### Spooler alert:

If the suggestion below works, you should try to understand the solution by reverse enginering it.

From the script you supplied, I guess your input data looks like this:

```
$inputFile = '
Student#   LAST  FIRST DN ERN HR STS DEG  CON  VER   GPA
9999-9999  Denty Bryon N  72  8  4   CER  CSC  2006A 3.43
1234-5678  Doe   John  D  65  7  5   CER2 CSC2 2006B 1.23
'
```

Using this [`ConvertFrom-SourceData`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable) cmdlet:

```
Get-Content .\STUDENTS.txt | ConvertFrom-SourceTable | ConvertTo-Html | Set-Content .\ITS3410-myname.htm
```

Results:

[image: HTML View]

```
$inputFile | ConvertFrom-SourceTable | ConvertTo-Html 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>Student#</th><th>LAST</th><th>FIRST</th><th>DN</th><th>ERN</th><th>HR</th><th>STS</th><th>DEG</th><th>CON</th><th>VER</th><th>GPA</th></tr>
<tr><td>9999-9999</td><td>Denty</td><td>Bryon</td><td>N</td><td>72</td><td>8</td><td>4</td><td>CER</td><td>CSC</td><td>2006A</td><td>3.43</td></tr>
<tr><td>1234-5678</td><td>Doe</td><td>John</td><td>D</td><td>65</td><td>7</td><td>5</td><td>CER2</td><td>CSC2</td><td>2006B</td><td>1.23</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

[**Related questions / other ways to do this**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ConvertFrom-SourceTable)