# Repeat a value in pscustomobject

Tags: powershell

I'm making a script that will take a text document and turn it into an HTML file. I'm pretty close using:

```
[PSCustomObject] @{
    'STUDENT #' = $STUDENTID
    LASTNAME = $LASTNAME
    FIRSTNAME = $FIRSTNAME
    DN = $DN
    ERN = $ERN
    HR = $HR
    STS = $STS
    DEG = $DEG
    CON = $CON
    VER = $VER
    MINOR = $MINOR
    GPA = $GPA
}
```

but the output is

```text
STUDENT #   LASTNAME    FIRSTNAME   DN  ERN HR  STS DEG CON VER   MINOR   GPA

5528-7375   DENTY       BRYON       N   72  8   4   CER CSC 2006A         3.43
```

What I need is to have that MINOR value there 3 more times ,I'm not able to add a duplicate value.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why repeat it in the object rather than the output?

Comment: You ask this same question twice here and on another site. The first time here you never showed the source doc and on the other site, you did. On your first post here and the other, your planned output did not include the Minor columns (4 of them). Your source doc had its own issue too as well. Either way, on your original posts here and the other, answers with the results you stated you wanted were provided. In this post, you are now stating slightly different results, you now want all 45 minor columns, and glad zett42 provided the format, but input was not an array but independent columns.

Comment: You might want to look into JSON.  JSON can accommodate hierarchical structures.  As to how that works with Format-Table and HTML, good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already noted, a `[PSCustomObject]` can't have duplicate properties.

As suggested in comments, you can repeat the property in the output instead. `Format-Table` happily accepts duplicate property names:

Simplified example:

```
[PSCustomObject]@{ x=42; y=21 } | Format-Table -Property x, x, y
```

Output:

```text
 x  x  y
 -  -  -
42 42 21
```

Comment: a good deal on this one, but as I stated in my comment, what the OP is showing/asking for is different from the original request and resource doc. [Here is the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66322069/converting-data-from-text-file-to-html) and [here is the link to the source file being parsed](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DQv0cI0MzCX-Kj9Wzz4fWHfAh--bHIpi/view?usp=sharing) the OP did not include on SO (or this one) but did on another site. Just so, you know what is really being worked on. Yet, we know, folks can/will change their use case. So, may be moot at this point.