# How can I make PowerShell display a specific word in a different color?

Tags: powershell

I am reading a log file dynamically using this command in PowerShell:

```
Get-Content logfilename.log -Wait
```

Is it possible to make it display certain words in color with some command?
For example I want all the places whereever there is an [Error] string in the file in red color.

Comment: See one of my other SO answers, which should address your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39486625/1368849

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to combine this with the `-wait` parameter, but this would do it without:

```
$Content = Get-Content logfilename.log

$Content | ForEach-Object {
    $Words = $_ -Split " "

    ForEach ($Word in $Words) {
        If ($Word -eq '[Error]'){
            Write-Host "$Word " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Red
        } Else {
            Write-Host "$Word " -NoNewline
        }
    }
    Write-Host ''
}
```

Comment: Note this assumes [Error] appears with spaces around it. If you want to match for it without spaces around it you'll need to match for the string and then split it.